# How to make an m x n cellarray from an m x 1 cellarray of 1 x n cellarrays, etc.?

Tags: matlab

[Sorry for the dumb question.  I'm completely new to MATLAB (and completely bewildered by it).]

I want to write a function `to2d`, taking as its only argument an *m* x 1 cellarray of 1 x *n* cellarrays, and returning the corresponding *m* x *n* cellarray.

For example, we would get stuff like:

```
>> A = {{1, 2}; {3, 4}; {5, 6}}

A = 

    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}

>> B = to2d(A)

B = 

    [1]    [2]
    [3]    [4]
    [5]    [6]
```

This question may be thought as a special case of the more general problem of programmatically passing arguments to a variable-arguments function when all one knows about these arguments is that they are stored in some cellarray.  In Python, one does this by using the `*`-syntax.  E.g.

```
func_with_indeterminate_args(*a_runtime_list_of_args)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just what the function `cat` doing:

```
>> cat(1,A{:})
ans = 
    [1]    [2]
    [3]    [4]
    [5]    [6]
```

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis: Suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is easy to answer:

```
function B = to2d(B)
    B = cat(1,B{:});
end
```

(Kudos to @Eastsun for the use of `cat` instead of `[B{:}]`).

As for your second question: arguments to any function can be captured and expanded in the user-accessible cell array `varargin`. The total number of arguments passed to *any* function can be accessed by `nargin`. Example:

```
function B = to2d(B, varargin)

    if nargin == 1
        B = reshape([B{:}], size(B,1),[])

    else
        for ii = 1:nargin
            fprintf('Parsing argument %d\n', ii); 
            varargin{ii}
        end

    end
end
```

then call

```
>> to2d(B)
B = 

    [1]    [2]
    [3]    [4]
    [5]    [6]

>> to2d(B, [0 0 0])
Parsing argument 1
ans = 
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}

Parsing argument 2
ans = 
    [0 0 0]
```